# Route optimization with QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network, route, optimization

I need to optimize the routes of a collection vehicle working with QGIS.

To do this I have a network layer and another with the collection points, both of then in a geopackage.

What I need is a new layer with the optimized route with the segment ordered and the collection points ordered.

I have tried the `v.net.salesman` algorithm from GRASS GIS ([manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.net.salesman.html)), but it is designed to routes between cities and does not have any way to set the direction of traffic and does not return an ordered layer.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you could try to generate v.net.salesman algorithm by regions or selecting some points.
I've posted an answer to a similar problem of my own.

I hope it could be useful for you @Raúl
[My question and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445422/v-net-salesman-problem-filling-in-dialog-box-parameters/446189#446189)