# V.NET.SALESMAN problem filling in dialog box parameters

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, parameters, travelling-salesman

I have a problem with the process of the algorithm "V.NET.SALESMAN" that surely is simple but I can't do it. I have read Grass’ documentation and similar posts here in Stack Exchange but in my case I have another problem.

I have two layers, one is a point layer with 638 elements (“medidores de luz” in spanish), and the other is a line layer (“calles medidores”). I need to find the shortest path to connect these points with the line layer.
As I have learned, I have to upload my layers to a Grass Geodatabase calling them with the prefix “grass” as shown in the photo:
[image]

After that I have connected the points to the lines through “V.NET”:

[image]

But my problem is when I am in the “V.NET.SALESMAN” ’s box dialogue. This is my error:

[image]

[image]

In spanish, it explains that the problem is in “CENTER_CATS” because it is not defined. But I don’t understand what I have to put in that parameter. I can’t select anything.
If I put a value in “CATS”, like 638 which is the total number of points of my layer, the problem is that “CITIES ARE NOT ENOUGH”:

[image]

I have seen in videos, as in these two links, that is posible to select the points to connect with “v.net.salesman”:
[Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21hfLJALiyU)
[Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_T3LFVwXVE)

But in my case is not possible when I try to select them for the “cats” parameters, it only let me to put values or make a “manual entry” instead of select the points in my map like the videos show.
I am using QGIS 2.22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by myself.

Parameters:
In Input arcs: You must select v.net algorithm's product
In Input nodes: You must select your line shape, not your point shape
In Cats, in my case, the correct expression is 1-638 without spaces between characteres.

I hope it could be useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that if I complete in "cats" parameters with some "ID" values from my points layer, for example from 1 to 10, "v.net.salesman" algorithm works. But I have 638 points and I would like to work with all of them.
The problem is that i have to manually load the 638 points.

[image]

I am thinking that a possible solution is an expression that contains the 638 values.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Beacuse I have tried to put this entry value:
[image]

But afther that this problem came up:
[image]

It explains that node 176 cannot be reached, but it is connected with "v.net" algorithm (green line is the correct result):

[image]

So I tried to make this until node 175 and it worked.

[image]

I'll investigate how to resolve it, what could happen with node 176?

In the meantime I will accept this answer as valid